# The method setOnAction((<no type> action) -> {}) is undefined for the type ChoiceBox<String>

Tags: javafx

whenever i tried to launch Javafx Application, i get the below error:
 "The method setOnAction(( action) -> {}) is undefined for the type ChoiceBox "

I thought this may be because of the imports missing in my code, then tried using the below imports:

import javafx.scene.control.*;

import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;

java -version in my terminal results:

java version "1.8.0_25"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

I am not sure what exactly is missing in the imports that is not letting me launch the UI. please help me resolve this.

Comment: Probably means `ChoiceBox` does not have a `setOnAction` method.

Comment: [The `onAction` property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceBox.html#onActionProperty) was added in version 8 update 60. It's not available in prior versions like the one you're using.

Comment: For some reason i don't have control to update java version, if not by updating to the version 8 update 60, can't i do it by importing the class that supports this?

Comment: You can try `choiceBox.addEventHandler(ActionEvent.ACTION, event -> {})`. Never tested so I don't know if it works, but probably no harm doing a quick test.

Comment: that's really an old fx version - even for fx8 ;) Best to update to a current release (java/fx12), or at least to a current version of 8, if for some reason you cant update to the newest.

Comment: thanks everyone for the help. changing JDK version locally worked, i am yet to try the below changes.

Answer (score 1):

Choicebox onAction() was introduced in JDK 8u60. Since yours is 8u25, it cannot access this method. If you are unable to update your Java version, then I suggest you use a ChangeListener to listen to changes done on your Choicebox, e.g.

```
     choiceBox.getItems().addAll("1","2","3","4");
     choiceBox.setValue("3");

     choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldNumber, Number newNumber) {
               //if you want to get the new value changed
                System.out.println(choiceBox.getItems().get((Integer) newNumber));
              //or you can invoke a function to do something else when value is changed
            }
        });
```